# Contingency table in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a table:

```
structure(list(Gender = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Female", 
"Male"), class = "factor"), AGE = c(20L, 20L, 15L, 16L, 13L), 
    BOTTLE_CNT = c(3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L), QUALIFICATION_DESC = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("12th and below", "Graduation"
    ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Gender", "AGE", "BOTTLE_CNT", 
"QUALIFICATION_DESC"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

I am building a shiny app to render a contingency table.  Since its a large table, I have used the following code:

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
    ui=shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
        fluidRow(
            column(3,
                   div(style = "font-size: 13px;", selectInput("colum", "Select Column Variable", ''))
            ),
            column(3,
                   div(style = "font-size: 13px;", selectInput("rowvar", label = "Select Row Variable", ''))
            )),
        fluidRow(
            tableOutput('foo')    
            )
    )),
    server=shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

        s <- reactive(
            a
            )


        observe({
            updateSelectInput(session, "colum", choices = sort(as.character(colnames(s()))))
        })

        observe({
            updateSelectInput(session, "rowvar", choices = sort(as.character(colnames(s()))))
        })

        output$foo <- renderTable({
            with(s(), table(input$rowvar, input$colum))
        })
    })
)
```

Instead of with(s(), table...... I have tried, using

```
xtabs(~input$rowvar + input$colum, s())
```

Neither works however both works if i use the column and row names directly.  What I want is for the row and column variables selected, a cross tab of those two variables is required.  I have tried using `CrossTable` from `library(gmodels)`, yet couldn't figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass objects to `table` and `input$rowvar` and `input$colum` are string.

You could try:

```
with(s(), table(get(input$rowvar),get(input$colum)))
```

If you want to use `xtabs`,  you could try creating the formula from the inputs using `paste` and `as.formula`:

```
xtabs(as.formula(paste0("~",input$rowvar,"+",input$colum)), s())
```

Also, instead of using the `updateSelectInput`, you could set the values the user can select directly in the `ui.R`.

```
selectInput("colum", "Select Column Variable", sort(as.character(colnames(a))))
```

If you want to use `updateSelectInput`, you might want to use validate/need in your renderTable, otherwise the app throws an error when it initialises because the `input$colum` and `input$rowvar` are `NULL` before they are updated:

```
output$foo <- renderTable({
      validate(need(input$rowvar,''),
               need(input$colum,''))
      xtabs(as.formula(paste0("~",input$rowvar,"+",input$colum)), s())
    })
```

Comment: This is really nice, NicE!!!.  Thanks a ton....I tried the first option and it worked like a charm....never knew about using 'get' function.  Will try all the other options too, it will be a great learning experience.

Comment: @LeArNr, I had a similar requirement and this post is quite useful. Can you confirm what is the importance of 's' and 'a' in your code? Accordingly I will need to update in my case. Thank you!!

Comment: @NicE, I had a similar requirement and this post is quite useful. your solution on get is quite helpful. Can you confirm what is the importance of 's' and 'a' in your code? Accordingly I will need to update in my case. Thank you!!

Comment: `a` is the user's table. `s` is the table wrapped in a `reactive`. It's not necessary here as it is not modified but I left it like that assuming this was a simplified example.

Comment: @NicE,Thank you for this explanation! I replaced a with my dataset which is a data.table and I started getting error "updateSelectInput: object 'session' not found". I am not sure why this error as have kept everything else same. Then I thought of setting the values in ui.R as you have suggested and instead of passing column names of a, I pass "data_input" which is my data.table, but it gives error that it does not find data_input. Do you have any idea what could be causing the error "updateSelectInput: object 'session' not found" ?

Comment: do you have `session` as an argument in your `shinyServer` function (`shinyServer(function(input, output, session)...`). For `data_input` that depends where you define it, maybe post a new question.

Comment: @NicE, Thank you !!!!! session was not present as an argument in ShinyServer. I added session and it worked !! I have voted +1 to your answer. Thank you once again for your quick revert :) !!

Comment: @NicE, I was trying the same xtab results to generate using CrossTable from gmodels but the output gets printed in the R console and not in the Shiny app. Do you have an idea why this could happen? CrossTable from gmodels has a nice feature of generating column / row / table percentages so was keen to have the output in Shiny. I have tried including the CrossTable function in renderTable / renderDataTable / renderText, but in all cases output table gets printed in R console only.